# Why does std::unique_ptr not permit type inference?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

It would be easier to read/write the second line of my example since the type of the template argument is obvious:

```
#include <memory>

struct Foo{};

int main()
{
  // redundant: good
  auto foo1 = std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo());
  // without explicitness: does not compile
  auto foo2 = std::unique_ptr(new Foo());
}
```

Of course, if you want to use polymorphism, we could always write:

```
auto base = std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived());
```

What is the reason for such a constraint?

Comment: Use `std::make_unique` (c++14), so no repetition.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not an issue that's... unique to [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) - instantiation of *template classes* does not automatically deduce the types from the constructors previous to C++17. This is why facilities such as [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique), [`std::make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) and [`std::make_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) exist: they use *template function argument deduction* to reduce boilerplate.

---

In C++17 you will be able to write:

```
auto foo2 = std::unique_ptr(new Foo());
```

thanks to [**class template deduction**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction) - assuming [P0433R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0433r0.html) is accepted, which adds a *deduction guide* to [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

The deduction guide is required because [`std::unique_ptr`'s constructor that takes a raw pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) uses the `pointer` type alias which is defined as follows:

> `std::remove_reference<Deleter>::type::pointer` if that type exists, otherwise `T*`. Must satisfy `NullablePointer`.

Type aliases like `pointer` are non-deducible contexts, so P0433R0 proposes the addition of:

```
template<class T> unique_ptr(T*) 
    -> unique_ptr<T, default_delete<T>>;

template<class T, class V> unique_ptr(T*, V) 
    -> unique_ptr<T, default_delete<T, V>>;  

template<class U, class V> unique_ptr(U, V) 
    -> unique_ptr<typename pointer_traits<typename V::pointer>::element_type, V>;
```

Which would enable *class template deduction* for `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Good answer, but should point out that although `std::make_unique<T,ARGS...>(...)` does reduce boilerplate, it can only deduce the types of the arguments to `T`'s c'tor--i.e it can only deduce the `ARGS...`.

Comment: According to the C++17 draft n4750 in `[unique.ptr.single.ctor]` the class template deduction is ill-formed: `If class template argument deduction (16.3.1.8) would select the function template corresponding to this constructor, then the program is ill-formed.`

Comment: I think this answer is outdated? The deduction guides have not been added, and for good reason. I added my own answer, but perhaps it is good to revise this one.

Answer (score 18):

The real reason for the absense of the deduction guides is this:

> There is no class template argument deduction from pointer type **[because it is impossible to distinguish a pointer obtained from array and non-array forms of new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr#Notes:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20class%20template%20argument,array%20and%20non%2Darray%20forms%20of%20new)**

Side note: The other answer promised that c++17 will allow this to compile:

This is simply not the case. Also For the above reason.